# Как при наведении на элемент менять свойства следующего за ним элемента

Tags: html, css

Всем привет.
Смотрите есть такое вот задание.

Чтобы иметь возможность при наведении на элемент менять свойства следующего за ним элемента, можно воспользоваться смежным селектором "+" https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы поняли (там один бордер) бордер-топ и у последнего дочернего ласт-чайлд (бордер боттом)
нужно что бы они меняли цвет, как на фото отмечено.

прохожу обучение это задание оттуда и не кто помочь не смог, а копировать у кого то не хочется, хочется понять почему не работают смежные свойства +

Есть такое HTML код:

```
<ul class="flex faq__list">
            <li class="flex faq__item">
               <button class="flex faq__btn">
                  <h4 class="faq__question">
                     Из&nbsp;чего формируется конечная стоимость проекта?
                  </h4>
                  <span class="faq__icon-wrapper">
                     <svg  class="faq__icon" width="31" height="31" viewBox="0 0 31 31" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                     <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15.0571 15.0571L15.0571 -1.31634e-06L15.9429 -1.31634e-06L15.9429 15.0571L23.8835 15.0571L31 15.0571L31 15.9429L15.9429 15.9429L15.9429 31L15.0571 31L15.0571 15.9429L2.42093e-06 15.9429L2.49836e-06 15.0571L15.0571 15.0571Z" fill="black"/>
                     </svg>
                  </span>
               </button>
            </li>

            <li class="flex faq__item">
               <button class="flex faq__btn">
                  <h4 class="faq__question">
                     У&nbsp;меня есть свой проект. Сможем&nbsp;ли мы&nbsp;его доработать&nbsp;/ реализовать?
                  </h4>
                  <span class="faq__icon-wrapper">
                     <svg  class="faq__icon" width="31" height="31" viewBox="0 0 31 31" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                     <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15.0571 15.0571L15.0571 -1.31634e-06L15.9429 -1.31634e-06L15.9429 15.0571L23.8835 15.0571L31 15.0571L31 15.9429L15.9429 15.9429L15.9429 31L15.0571 31L15.0571 15.9429L2.42093e-06 15.9429L2.49836e-06 15.0571L15.0571 15.0571Z" fill="black"/>
                     </svg>
                  </span>
               </button>
            </li>

            <li class="flex faq__item">
               <button class="flex faq__btn">
                  <h4 class="faq__question">
                     Я&nbsp;выбираю между разными компаниями. В&nbsp;чём ваше отличие?
                  </h4>
                  <span class="faq__icon-wrapper">
                     <svg  class="faq__icon" width="31" height="31" viewBox="0 0 31 31" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                     <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15.0571 15.0571L15.0571 -1.31634e-06L15.9429 -1.31634e-06L15.9429 15.0571L23.8835 15.0571L31 15.0571L31 15.9429L15.9429 15.9429L15.9429 31L15.0571 31L15.0571 15.9429L2.42093e-06 15.9429L2.49836e-06 15.0571L15.0571 15.0571Z" fill="black"/>
                     </svg>
                  </span>
               </button>
            </li>

            <li class="flex faq__item">
               <button class="flex faq__btn">
                  <h4 class="faq__question">
                     Могу&nbsp;ли я&nbsp;делегировать вам работу&nbsp;/ согласование с&nbsp;подрядчиком&nbsp;/ организацией?
                  </h4>
                  <span class="faq__icon-wrapper">
                     <svg  class="faq__icon" width="31" height="31" viewBox="0 0 31 31" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                     <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15.0571 15.0571L15.0571 -1.31634e-06L15.9429 -1.31634e-06L15.9429 15.0571L23.8835 15.0571L31 15.0571L31 15.9429L15.9429 15.9429L15.9429 31L15.0571 31L15.0571 15.9429L2.42093e-06 15.9429L2.49836e-06 15.0571L15.0571 15.0571Z" fill="black"/>
                     </svg>
                  </span>
               </button>
            </li>

            <li class="flex faq__item">
               <button class="flex faq__btn">
                  <h4 class="faq__question">
                     Могу&nbsp;ли я&nbsp;вернуть деньги на&nbsp;каком-либо из&nbsp;этапов работ?
                  </h4>
                  <span class="faq__icon-wrapper">
                     <svg  class="faq__icon" width="31" height="31" viewBox="0 0 31 31" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                     <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15.0571 15.0571L15.0571 -1.31634e-06L15.9429 -1.31634e-06L15.9429 15.0571L23.8835 15.0571L31 15.0571L31 15.9429L15.9429 15.9429L15.9429 31L15.0571 31L15.0571 15.9429L2.42093e-06 15.9429L2.49836e-06 15.0571L15.0571 15.0571Z" fill="black"/>
                     </svg>
                  </span>
               </button>
            </li>
         </ul>
```

И есть вот такой вот CSS:

```
/* START - FAQ. SECTION */

.faq {
   padding-top: 111px;
}

.faq__title {
   margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.faq__list {
   min-height: auto;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
}

.faq__btn {
   width: 100%;
   min-height: 110px;
   padding-top: 30px;
   padding-bottom: 30px;
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: center;

   border-top: 1px solid var(--brdr-standart);
}

.faq__item:last-child .faq__btn {
   border-bottom: 1px solid var(--brdr-standart);
}

.faq__question {
   font-weight: 700;
   font-size: var(--fnt-tfr);
   line-height: 32px;
   color: #333;
}

.faq__icon-wrapper {
   position: relative;
   border-radius: 100%;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: var(--brdr-standart);

   font-size: 35px;
   transition-property: transform;
   transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}

.faq__icon {
   position: absolute;
   top: 9px;
   left: 10px;
}

.faq__item {
   transition: border-color .2s ease-in-out;
}

/* ################# */

/* @ - START __ STYLE HOW WE WORK SEC. */

.faq__btn:hover,
.faq__question:hover,
.faq__icon-wrapper:hover  {
   color: var(--brdr-hover);
   border-color: var(--brdr-hover);
}

.faq__btn:hover + .faq__btn {
   border-color: var(--brdr-hover);
}

/* # - END __ STYLE - F.A.Q. SEC. */
/* # - END __ F.A.Q. SECTION */

/* ################# */
/* ################# */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
/* START - FAQ. SECTION */

.faq {
   padding-top: 111px;
}

.faq__title {
   margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.faq__list {
   min-height: auto;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
}

.faq__btn {
   width: 100%;
   min-height: 110px;
   padding-top: 30px;
   padding-bottom: 30px;
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: center;

   border-top: 1px solid var(--brdr-standart);
}

.faq__item:last-child .faq__btn {
   border-bottom: 1px solid var(--brdr-standart);
}

.faq__question {
   font-weight: 700;
   font-size: var(--fnt-tfr);
   line-height: 32px;
   color: #333;
}

.faq__icon-wrapper {
   position: relative;
   border-radius: 100%;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: var(--brdr-standart);

   font-size: 35px;
   transition-property: transform;
   transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}

.faq__icon {
   position: absolute;
   top: 9px;
   left: 10px;
}

.faq__item {
   transition: border-color .2s ease-in-out;
}

/* ################# */

/* @ - START __ STYLE HOW WE WORK SEC. */

.faq__btn:hover,
.faq__question:hover,
.faq__icon-wrapper:hover  {
   color: var(--brdr-hover);
   border-color: var(--brdr-hover);
}

.faq__item:hover + .faq__item .faq__btn {
   border-color:red;
}

/* # - END __ STYLE - F.A.Q. SEC. */
/* # - END __ F.A.Q. SECTION */

/* ################# */
/* ################# */
```

```html
<ul class="flex faq__list">
  <li class="flex faq__item">
    <button class="flex faq__btn">
      <h4 class="faq__question">
        Из&nbsp;чего формируется конечная стоимость проекта?
      </h4>
      <span class="faq__icon-wrapper">
        <svg class="faq__icon" width="31" height="31" viewBox="0 0 31 31" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15.0571 15.0571L15.0571 -1.31634e-06L15.9429 -1.31634e-06L15.9429 15.0571L23.8835 15.0571L31 15.0571L31 15.9429L15.9429 15.9429L15.9429 31L15.0571 31L15.0571 15.9429L2.42093e-06 15.9429L2.49836e-06 15.0571L15.0571 15.0571Z" fill="black" />
        </svg>
      </span>
    </button>
  </li>

  <li class="flex faq__item">
    <button class="flex faq__btn">
      <h4 class="faq__question">
        У&nbsp;меня есть свой проект. Сможем&nbsp;ли мы&nbsp;его доработать&nbsp;/ реализовать?
      </h4>
      <span class="faq__icon-wrapper">
        <svg class="faq__icon" width="31" height="31" viewBox="0 0 31 31" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15.0571 15.0571L15.0571 -1.31634e-06L15.9429 -1.31634e-06L15.9429 15.0571L23.8835 15.0571L31 15.0571L31 15.9429L15.9429 15.9429L15.9429 31L15.0571 31L15.0571 15.9429L2.42093e-06 15.9429L2.49836e-06 15.0571L15.0571 15.0571Z" fill="black" />
        </svg>
      </span>
    </button>
  </li>

  <li class="flex faq__item">
    <button class="flex faq__btn">
      <h4 class="faq__question">
        Я&nbsp;выбираю между разными компаниями. В&nbsp;чём ваше отличие?
      </h4>
      <span class="faq__icon-wrapper">
        <svg class="faq__icon" width="31" height="31" viewBox="0 0 31 31" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15.0571 15.0571L15.0571 -1.31634e-06L15.9429 -1.31634e-06L15.9429 15.0571L23.8835 15.0571L31 15.0571L31 15.9429L15.9429 15.9429L15.9429 31L15.0571 31L15.0571 15.9429L2.42093e-06 15.9429L2.49836e-06 15.0571L15.0571 15.0571Z" fill="black" />
        </svg>
      </span>
    </button>
  </li>

  <li class="flex faq__item">
    <button class="flex faq__btn">
      <h4 class="faq__question">
        Могу&nbsp;ли я&nbsp;делегировать вам работу&nbsp;/ согласование с&nbsp;подрядчиком&nbsp;/ организацией?
      </h4>
      <span class="faq__icon-wrapper">
        <svg class="faq__icon" width="31" height="31" viewBox="0 0 31 31" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15.0571 15.0571L15.0571 -1.31634e-06L15.9429 -1.31634e-06L15.9429 15.0571L23.8835 15.0571L31 15.0571L31 15.9429L15.9429 15.9429L15.9429 31L15.0571 31L15.0571 15.9429L2.42093e-06 15.9429L2.49836e-06 15.0571L15.0571 15.0571Z" fill="black" />
        </svg>
      </span>
    </button>
  </li>

  <li class="flex faq__item">
    <button class="flex faq__btn">
      <h4 class="faq__question">
        Могу&nbsp;ли я&nbsp;вернуть деньги на&nbsp;каком-либо из&nbsp;этапов работ?
      </h4>
      <span class="faq__icon-wrapper">
        <svg class="faq__icon" width="31" height="31" viewBox="0 0 31 31" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15.0571 15.0571L15.0571 -1.31634e-06L15.9429 -1.31634e-06L15.9429 15.0571L23.8835 15.0571L31 15.0571L31 15.9429L15.9429 15.9429L15.9429 31L15.0571 31L15.0571 15.9429L2.42093e-06 15.9429L2.49836e-06 15.0571L15.0571 15.0571Z" fill="black" />
        </svg>
      </span>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Псевдоклассы "+" или "~" применяются только к элементам с общим потомком. *У вас очень много ошибок в html. Почитайте про вложенности тегов и заголовки.

Comment: Да, HINT сообщил об этом) спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена таким образом.

.faq__item - у были заданы бордеры.

и применены эти стили.

```
.faq__item:hover {
   border-color: var(--brdr-hover);
}

.faq__item:hover + li.faq__item {
   border-color: var(--brdr-hover);
```